# How to configure PM2 to run .NET projects?

Tags: .net, .net-core, pm2

How can I configure PM2 to run a .NET project? I created the following configuration file, named it `ecosystem.config.js` and saved it in the solution root directory.

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
    {
      name: "MyProject",
      script: "dotnet run --no-launch-profile --project MyProject.csproj",
      cwd: "./src/Services/MyProject",
      env: {
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://localhost:5801",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Local"
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

When I run PM2 with the command `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` I get the followind error:

```
PM2][ERROR] Error: Script not found: C:\Code\Work\src\Services\MyProject\dotnet run --no-launch-profile --project MyProject.csproj
```

It appears that PM2 is expecting (reasonably) that the `script` property in the configuration file would contain the path to a script file, whereas in fact `script` direcly contains the code to run, i.e. the content of a script, rather than a path.

Is it possible to configure PM2 to run a .NET project along these lines? I'm running on Windows 11.